# ec2 instance always timeout in about 60 seconds?

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Why my ec2 instance always timeout in about 60 seconds when I access http or https? After about 60 seconds always return:

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out" The Web Server
>   may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it
>   from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later
>   time.
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

and some times return:

> **Gateway Timeout**
>
> The gateway did not receive a timely response from the update server or application.

I use apache web server and PHP with max timeout. 
I dont use ELB/Load Balancer in my EC2, and I never create any ELB. I tried to find solution in internet but always found ELB setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html) I just need to run the command below

```
/sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=200 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=200 net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5
```

I tried and not working, but after I edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add following code:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=200
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=5
```

Then I rebooted my instance, and now the timeout is longer.

Answer (score 2):

In your apache/vhost config you need to set the Timeout directive to the desired timeout value.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

> **Description**:  Amount of time the server will wait for certain events before failing a request
>   **Syntax**:   TimeOut seconds
>   **Default**:  TimeOut 60
>   **Context**:  server config, virtual host

Comment: I already set it, the error came from TCP not apache.